# In <input> can I exclude certain type of files?

Tags: html, input

Something like this but that **excludes** all types of videos/images/audios:

```
<input accept="video/*" type='file' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like this, There is no `exclude="video/*"` in HTML, you can type in all files you allow, but user still will be able to upload any file they want.

[image]

Because in dialog they will be able to change file types, they'r seeing.

You can deffinetly check if file is Video, Image or Audio using JS, and then not allow it.